# Does TypeScript infer castings when assigning anonymous objects to a typed property?

Tags: typescript

Bit of a convoluted example, but I'm not sure why TypeScript isn't throwing an error here.

```
export class Square {
    width: number;
}

export class MyShapeBox<T> {
    shape: T;
}

var mySquareBox = new MyShapeBox<Square>();

var rectangle = { width: 3, height: 10 };

// Should this not fail?
mySquareBox.shape = rectangle;
```

[Online version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20class%20Square%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width:%20number;%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20MyShapeBox%20%7B%0A%09shape:%20T;%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20mySquareBox%20=%20new%20MyShapeBox();%0A%0Avar%20rectangle%20=%20%7B%20width:%203,%20height:%2010%20%7D;%0A%0A//%20Should%20this%20not%20fail?%0AmySquareBox.shape%20=%20rectangle;)

From discussion we've had, the best guess is that TypeScript is casting to a base type when assigning the value. But that means the class is really acting more like an interface.

And I know that it doesn't make any difference to the underlying JavaScript that's generated.

I'm just really curious as to why this is the behaviour since I'd expect it to throw an error, much in the same way it does if you try and assign an unknown property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is allowed in typescript because the shape of your rectangle matches the shape of square (they both contain `width`. If you comment out the width property in your rectangle like below:

```
var rectangle = { /*width: 3, */ height: 10 };
```

Now it doesn't compile anymore because the shape of rectangle doesn't match Square anymore and the assignment `mySquareBox.shape = rectangle` fails because of that.

From the TypeScript site:

> One of TypeScript's core principles is that type-checking focuses on the 'shape' that values have. This is sometimes called "duck typing" or "structural subtyping". [Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook)

The quote from above is the reason it compiles without errors.

**edit**

I only talked about removing width from the rectangle object but the same applies if you add a `dummy` property to the `Square` class because after you do that, the shapes again don't match.